# How do I get my event listener to respond to the initial value of my slider input?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, slider

I finally got my etch a sketch to respond to my slider 'input' element. I created a transformGrid function to organize this. The problem now is that upon page load, there is no printed grid till i move the slider. How do i get my eventlistener to respond to the initial value of the slider? So i have a grid of 16 printed at the initial page load. I'm trying to avoid hardcoding a print of 16 :/.

```
function resetGrid() {
    
    while (gridContainer.hasChildNodes()) {
        gridContainer.removeChild(gridContainer.lastChild);
    }
    gridPrint = false;
}

function transformGrid(e) {
    while (gridPrint) {
        resetGrid();
    }
    
    let dimension = e.target.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        // create a div for each row
        const gridRow = document.createElement('div');      
        gridRow.classList.add('grid-row');
        gridContainer.appendChild(gridRow);

        for (let j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            const gridSquare = document.createElement('div');
            gridSquare.classList.add('grid-square');
            gridSquare.style.width = `${GRIDLENGTH / dimension}px`;
            gridSquare.style.height = `${GRIDLENGTH / dimension}px`;
            gridRow.appendChild(gridSquare);
        }
    }
    gridPrint = true;
}

gridControl.addEventListener('input', transformGrid);
```

Comment: What's the reason for the `while (gridPrint)` loop? You'll never loop more than once because `resetGrid()` always sets the variable to false.

Comment: Most most of the code of `transformGrid()` to a function that takes `dimension` as an argument. Then call that at top-level with the initial value of the slider.

Comment: @Barmar, it's a remnant of changes I made while trying (and failing) to solve a problem I encountered previously. It was originally an if statement. Thank you! I actually solved it a bit ago by doing just that! took most of transformGrid and moved to createGrid(dimension).